# Apex app authorization scheme not working after import

Tags: oracle-apex

My Authorization Scheme was working as expected in my personal workspace but once I imported it into another workspace the Authorization no longer works.

I'm using Exists SQL Query with `SELECT ROLE FROM USERDETAILS WHERE ROLE IN ('Admin')`. I've checked the table and everything is setup as per my personal workspace

I'm using Apex 20.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application's shared components -> authorization schemes -> your specific authorization scheme details -> evaluation point and then authorization scheme tab's scheme type. (I assume you need to check your query as the explanation: A query that causes the authorization scheme to pass if it returns at least one row and causes the scheme to fail if it returns no rows.)

```
select null
from apex_workspace_group_users
where user_name  = :APP_USER
      and group_name = 'ADMIN'
```